# How to check at compile time that a lookup table has the correct size?

Tags: c++

I'm hard-coding values for a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table). The required number of elements comes from an included file which might change at some point in the future. So I want to make sure *at compile time* that the number of elements I specify really matches the required number.

Have a look at this code:

```
#include <array>

// Assume this comes from some included file
constexpr size_t elementCount = 5;

int main() {
    // This works.
    const std::array<int, elementCount> lookup { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };

    // But so does this.
    const std::array<int, elementCount> lookup2 { 2, 4, 6 };

    return 0;
}
```

`std::array` seems like the perfect fit for a lookup table because its size is fixed at compile time. However, there is no way I know of to ensure that it is initialized with the correct number of elements. Due to [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), the example compiles fine even if I specify too few elements.

I came up with the following workaround, but it feels pretty ugly:

```
#include <array>

template<class T> std::array<T, 1> makeArray(T e1) {
    return { e1 };
}

template<class T> std::array<T, 2> makeArray(T e1, T e2) {
    return { e1, e2 };
}

template<class T> std::array<T, 3> makeArray(T e1, T e2, T e3) {
    return { e1, e2, e3 };
}

template<class T> std::array<T, 4> makeArray(T e1, T e2, T e3, T e4) {
    return { e1, e2, e3, e4 };
}

template<class T> std::array<T, 5> makeArray(T e1, T e2, T e3, T e4, T e5) {
    return { e1, e2, e3, e4, e5 };
}

// ... and so on; these functions would live in some utility header file.

// Assume this comes from some included file
constexpr size_t elementCount = 5;

int main() {
    // This works.
    const std::array<int, elementCount> lookup = makeArray(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);

    // This doesn't. :-)
    const std::array<int, elementCount> lookup2 = makeArray(2, 4, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

So the question is: **Is there an elegant way to ensure at compile time that I'm specifying the correct number of elements for a lookup table I'm hardcoding?** Note that the data type needn't be `std::array`; any sequence container that indexes in constant time will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can templatize your `make_array` (similar to [`make_array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array) from Library Fundamentals TS):

```
template<typename T, typename... Params>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Params)> make_array(Params&&... ps) {
    return { std::forward<Params>(ps)... };
}
```

Now, just create your array:

```
int main() {
    // This works.
    const auto lookup = makeArray<int>(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);
    static_assert(lookup.size() == elementCount, "");


    // This doesn't. :-)
    const auto lookup2 = makeArray<int>(2, 4, 6);
    static_assert(lookup2.size() == elementCount, ""); // error
}
```

If you want, you can move the assert to your `make_array` function (or make a wrapper for it), but then, perhaps a name change would be in order:

```
template<typename T, typename... Params>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Params)> make_lookup_array(Params&&... ps) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Params) == elementCount, "must be equal!");
    return { std::forward<Params>(ps)... };
}
```

Comment: That's much better than my overloads. I didn't realize there was a technical specification for a make_array function. I guess I'll just stick to the "official" signature; then I can switch to std::make_array once it gets standardized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **variadic templates**:

```
#include <array>

// Assume this comes from some included file
constexpr size_t elementCount = 5;

template<class first, class ... T>
std::array<first, 1 + sizeof...(T)> makeArray(first e1, T ... rest) {
    static_assert(1 + sizeof...(T) == elementCount, "Must match elementCount");
    return {  std::forward<first>(e1), std::forward<T>(rest) ...};
}

int main() {
    // This works.
    const auto lookup = makeArray(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);

    // This doesn't. :-)
    const auto lookup2 = makeArray(2, 4, 6);
}
```

You can try it [here](http://ideone.com/iHVp6d)

EDIT:

The use of both `class first` and `class ... T` allow the compiler to auto deduce the type of the elements. That is, the type of the first parameter to makeArray defines `std::array::value_type`.

Comment: @krzaq Because of the use of both `class first` and `class ... T`.